# (ASP.NET) Can you do a String.Format on a web.config key/value?

Tags: web-config, string.format

This might be a god awful question but I'm not sure why it won't let me do this.

I have a URL I need to store in Web.config, which has a dynamic parameter pulled from the web page.

So I want to store:

```
        <add key="TestURL" 
value="https://test/subscribe?msisdn={0}&code=1&pass=2"/>
```

It doesn't let me do this.  After the {0} it errors at the "&".

Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong here?  Do I need to escape the character?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this instead,

```
<add key="TestURL" value="https://test/subscribe?msisdn={0}&amp;code=1&amp;pass=2"/>
```

Notice the escaped ampersands.

Comment: @JackM whatever values you want to place in the add tag value attribute just need to be HTML encoded. If you have a hard time figuring out how to encode a value properly you can write something that will have .Net do it for you using the HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx

Comment: jpj625 is accurate in his statement that Web.config files are stored in XML text files. See this StackOverflow question about XML document escape characters:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents

Answer (score 3):

Config files are XML, and as such, require XML entities to be escaped. The problem isn't your {0} for use in formatting, it's the & that must be escaped as

```
&amp;
```